# Python error indentation

Tags: python-2.7, odoo

i have indentation error but i dont know how to solve it , i tried to unindent and indent but it isnt work please help me this is my code python :

```
class account_invoice(osv.osv):
    _name = "account.invoice"
    _inherit = "account.invoice"
    _columns = {

       'methodedepaiement': fields.selection([
            ('cheque','Chèque'),
            ('virement','Virement'),
            ('espece','Espèce'),
            ('carteb','Carte bancaire'),
            ('prelev','Prélèvement'),], string='Méthode de paiement'),

    }

    @api.multi
    def amount_to_text_fr(self, amount, currency='Dirhams'):
        return amount_to_text_fr(amount,currency)

    @api.depends('control_amount_total')
    def _compute_control_amount_total_text(self):
        for record in self:
            if record.control_amount_total :
                amount = record.control_amount_total
                list = str(amount).split('.')
                start_word = amount_to_text_fr(abs(int(list[0])),  'Dirhams').split('Dirhams')[0]
                end_word = amount_to_text_fr(int(list[1]),  'Centimes').split('Centimes')[0]
                record.control_amount_total_text = start_word + ' Dirhams et ' + end_word + ' Centimes'
                #self.control_amount_total_text = amount_to_text(self.control_amount_total,'fr','Dirhams')
```

i had problem in the function

Comment: you could give us the error stack trace to check where exactly the problem is? I suggest you use an IDE to help with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Spyder IDE

Source Menu -> Fix Indentation 
[image]